# Add a suffix in the last part of lines that contain ">"

Tags: text, suffix

I have a text file that have the following structure:

```
>RF1CLC1
DATADATADATADATA
>RF1CLC2
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
>RF2CLC13
DATADATADATADATA
>RF2CLC24
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
```

and so on.

I'm looking for a way to add a suffix "_c1_g1_i1" at the end of the line containing ">", resulting in:

```
>RF1CLC1_c1_g1_i1
DATADATADATADATA
>RF1CLC2_c1_g1_i1
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
>RF2CLC13_c1_g1_i1
DATADATADATADATA
>RF2CLC24_c1_g1_i1
DATADATADATADATA
DATADATADATADATA
```

awk, sed or perl/python solution is preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you attempted, and can you show us?

Comment: I have tried with sed: sed -i "/>/ s/$)/)_c1_g1_i1/g" but I'm getting the same file

Comment: Nevermind, I got it with sed -i '/>/ s/$/_c1_g1_i1/' TEST.fasta, a minor syntax problem, thanks for making me reviewing that!

Comment: Now, for added points, post a full answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with sed -i "/>/ s/$)/)_c1_g1_i1/g" TEST.fasta but thanks to roelofs I realized that the syntax was wrong.

Used

```
sed -i '/>/ s/$/_c1_g1_i1/' TEST.fasta
```

and worked out well.

Thanks.